# How do I transfer .blend files to a new PC and still keep all the materials?

Tags: materials, blend-files

I have been using my laptop for the longest time with blender. I recently got a new PC. When I copied the .blend file and dropped it in my new PC, no materials were on my mesh. How do I fix this??

Answer (score 2):

Pack all your files into the .blend before you save and copy. See below:

[image: PackFiles]

Comment: Can you pack MATERIALS? It is for packing in textures right?

Comment: If you mean procedural materials, I don't think you don't need to pack them. Materials based on texture maps, will need to be packed.

Comment: Packing is just for images used as textures. But you can also just make a copy of the folders where you keep everything. Just replicate the same folder structure on the new computer and your blend files should open just as they did in the old one.